# How to use Phantomjs evaluate to return anything from document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) of phantomjs, because I want to use phantom with node.

My goal here is to get element from given position on given webpage. Everything I try to do I always get *null*, *empty string* or *Promise {  }*

Basicly here is my code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var sitepage;
var url = "http://amazon.com";

phantom.create().then(function(ph){
    return ph.createPage();
}).then(function(page){
    var pageWidth = parseInt("1920px", 10);
    var pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10);
    sitepage = page;
    sitepage.property('settings', {loadImages: false});
    sitepage.property('viewportSize', { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight });
    return sitepage.open(req.query.url);
}).then(function(status){
    if (status == "success") {
        var x = 888;
        var y = 777;

        var element = sitepage.evaluate(function(x, y) {
            return document.elementFromPoint(x, y).outerHTML;
        }, x, y);

        return element;
    }

    return '404';
}).then(function(content){
    console.log(content);

    page.close();
    ph.exit();      
});
```

Inside the last *.then()* I want to be able to print or save to a variable anything what evaluate returns.

I have tried this many ways and spent multiple hours with no success so far.

EDIT:
Package I'm using has following example in readme:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
}).then(function(html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

Not sure if I used it right, but anything I tried hasnt worked yet :\

Comment: what should the `ph` variable point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three errors in your code:

#### 1. Undefined `ph`

In the last `then` callback your `ph` variable was undefined, since it was scoped (and lost) after the first `then` callback.

So, by modifying the first callback to break the `ph` variable out of the scope we can use it inside the last callback:

```
var ph;

phantom.create().then(function(pahntomObj){
    ph = pahntomObj;
    return ph.createPage();
})...
```

#### 2. Wrong variable

The second error was, that you're using an undefined variable `req.query.url`, while you probably should be using your own `url` variable:

```
return sitepage.open(url);
```

#### 3. Clearing too much settings

The third problem was, that you were overriding the `settings` property object with `{loadImages: false}`, while the full object contained in the `settings` property was originally:

```
{ XSSAuditingEnabled: false,
  javascriptCanCloseWindows: true,
  javascriptCanOpenWindows: true,
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  loadImages: true,
  localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: false,
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1',
  webSecurityEnabled: true }
```

So just calling `sitepage.property('settings', {loadImages: false});` clears all the other flags (like userAgent, javascriptEnabled etc).

To fix this, you should:

1. Read the `settings` property
2. Modify the object locally
3. Save the modified object to `settings`

This translates to code:

```
.then(function() {
    return sitepage.property('settings');
}).then(function(settings) {
    settings.loadImages = false;
    return sitepage.property('settings', settings);
})
```

### Solution

Combining these, we'll get a working code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var sitepage;
var url = "http://amazon.com";

var ph;
phantom.create().then(function(phObj){
    ph = phObj;
    return ph.createPage();
}).then(function(page){
    sitepage = page;
    var pageWidth = parseInt("1920px", 10);
    var pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10);
    return sitepage.property('viewportSize', { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight });
}).then(function() {
    return sitepage.property('settings');
}).then(function(settings) {
    settings.loadImages = false;
    return sitepage.property('settings', settings);
}).then(function() {
    return sitepage.open(url);
}).then(function(status){
    if (status == "success") {
        var x = 888;
        var y = 777;

        var element = sitepage.evaluate(function(x, y) {
            return document.elementFromPoint(x, y).outerHTML;
        }, x, y);

        return element;
    }

    return '404';
}).then(function(content){
    console.log(content);

    sitepage.close();
    ph.exit();      
});
```